# Determining the regular expression library supplied by the system

Tags: regular-expression, libraries

I was attempting to use the following regexp in `less` yesterday:
`^\+1[[:space:]]*$`, which worked for me in `grep`. This didn't work in `less`, so I checked the manpage to see what it does support, and found this:

```
/pattern
    Search forward in the file for the N-th line containing the pattern. N defaults to 1. The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system. 
    The search starts at the first line displayed (but see the -a and -j options, which change this).
```

I asked this question in `/dev/chat`, and there wasn't much of a consensus (to me) on what library is used, or even the priority in choosing a library, let alone a way to actually check what is currently used. I currently use Fedora 30, but hopefully the answers are Linux-agnostic.

So, the questions are:

1. How do I determine what regexp library is supplied by my system that `less` would use?
2. What does it mean for a regexp library to be supplied by my system?
3. What other utilities and programs does this supplied regexp library affect?
4. If you mention any specific regexp libraries that could be/are used by the system, please provide a link to a page on that regexp library, if possible.

`ldd` shows

```
[unge@localhost ~]$ ldd "$(command -v less)"
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff040e0000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f6733339000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6733173000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f67333be000)
```

Comment: So it seems as if it is not _dynamically_ linked against something like a PCRE library at least. Not having a Fedora system at hand, I would therefore _guess_ that this means it would _at least_ support POSIX extended regular expressions (provided via the C library).

Comment: @Kusalananda So it could still be statically linked then? How do you know it's not linked against a PCRE library? It would have said as much in the output? Is there a way to do better than a guess?

Comment: tl;dr; write your regexp as `^\+1\s*$`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you’re referring to a `less` binary, `less --version` will tell you which regex implementation it’s using; for example

   ```
   $ less --version
   less 487 (GNU regular expressions)
   Copyright (C) 1984-2016  Mark Nudelman

   less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
   For information about the terms of redistribution,
   see the file named README in the less distribution.
   Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
   ```

   At build time, the library is determined by the `--with-regex` given to `./configure`:

   ```
   --with-regex=LIB        select regular expression library (LIB is one of auto,none,gnu,pcre,posix,regcmp,re_comp,regcomp,regcomp-local) [auto]
   ```

   and traced in the build logs.

   Some of the implementations are available as separate libraries (`pcre` for example), others are included in the C library (`gnu` for example), one of them is included in the `less` source code (`regcomp-local`).
2. I think the expression refers to whichever library was available on the system `less` was built on, in the context of the `auto` option at least. Once built, a given `less` binary won’t change its regex implementation.
3. None.

The supported libraries are:

- [POSIX `regcomp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) (identified as “POSIX” in the version string);
- [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) (“PCRE”);
- the GNU C library’s `re_compile_pattern` (“GNU”);
- `regcmp` (“V8”);
- Unix V8 `regcomp`, either provided by the system or `less`’ own copy (Henry Spencer’s implementation; “Spencer V8”);
- `re_comp` (“BSD”).

Comment: Next issue is to unpack what "GNU regular expressions" actually means.

Comment: @Kusalananda it means `gnu` in `./configure`, *i.e.* `re_compile_pattern` in the GNU C library.